# Kotlin SimpleDateFormat to String

Tags: android, string, kotlin, simpledateformat

In Kotlin, I'am trying to retrieve the SimpleDateFormat to a String variable but I receive Error.
Any help please?

```
var someDate:SimpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("2020-05-16")
var someText:String = someDate.toString()  --> Error
```

Comment: That's not a valid date format.  It should look something like this: `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: Be aware that Kotlin has its own date-time handling, largely aped from the industry-leading *java.time* classes bundled with Java. Never use the terrible `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date`, and `Calendar` classes in Java — now legacy as of *java.time* defined in JSR 310.

Comment: What error are you getting? Please paste error message and/or stack trace into the question. So we may help you with the error you are getting.

Comment: When I hand translate your code to Java, it works, and `someText` becomes `java.text.SimpleDateFormat@7da0adc` (in one run). Maybe not very useful, but not an error.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** I do not need Kotlin syntax but AFAIK, Java code can be executed as it is in Kotlin or at least anyone working with Kotlin should be able to translate a Java code easily into Kotlin syntax.

---

The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Note:** If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

**Using the modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2020, 5, 16);
        String formatted = date.toString();
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-05-16
```

Note that [`LocalDate#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString--) already returns the string in the ISO-8601 format, which is the format you want the output string in, and therefore you do need a formatter to get the string into the required format.

**Using the legacy API:**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2020);
        // Note that in java.util date-time API, January is month, 0
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 4);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 16);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = calendar.getTime();
        String formatted = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-05-16
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin API levels 26 or greater:

```
val parsedDate = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-12-14T09:55:00", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
val formattedDate = parsedDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"))
```

Below API levels 26:

```
val parser =  SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")
val formattedDate = formatter.format(parser.parse("2018-12-14T09:55:00"))
```

Comment: Are you mixing up Android level 26 with Kotlin level 26? And in the case of Android, that limitation is gone when using new tooling with API desugaring feature.